# php-fpm + nginx + upload results in 502 Bad Request recv() failed()

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, php, bad-request

I´m struggeling with a problem while uploading files to my server.

I use the following:

- Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
- nginx 1.4.6
- php5-fpm 5.5.9

The applications which should receive the files is on top of Zend Framework 2.4.0.

Everytime I want to upload a file, I got a 502 Bad Request response.

The error.log of nginx shows:

```
[error] 21217#0: *5 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

I read so much about this error but nothing really helped.

I did:

- disable opcache in php.ini
- switched from sockets to tcp for php-fpm
- set filesizes for php
- set timeouts for nginx and php-fpm

If anyone has an idea it would be very nice if you could help a little bit :)

Greetz
Nilson

Answer (score 1):

**Try to open your fastcgi pool config:**
vim /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

**Change listen to:**
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

**Open your nginx site config:**
vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-site.conf

**Replace unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock by:**
127.0.0.1:9000;

Restart nginx and php5-fpm.

Comment: Why? Can you please provide the rationale behind using tcp/ip instead of sockets?

Comment: @foozy I saw this error in a lot of installations of ubuntu 14.04, cause by default, php versions in ubuntu 14.04 comes configurated to run by tcp, instead of .sock. In earlier versions the default was .sock